# Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

Getting this exception while connecting to Amazon S3 Bucket to download an object.

> Exception in thread “main” com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to
>   execute HTTP request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please post the answer as a post, not inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to:

Java 6 or earlier clients ignore SNI alerts but in Java 7/8 clients, SNI checking is enabled by default.

Resolution:

You can disable SNI alerts by specifying the JVM system parameter. Just add -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false in eclipse.ini and restart eclipse.